# Problem rewriting scala method post upgrade to scala 2.12 (from 2.11)

Tags: string, scala, scala-2.12

I have the following small but complex method in my project:

```
private def indent ( s : String )
  = s.lines.toStream match {
    case h +: t =>
      ( ("- " + h) +: t.map{"| " + _} ) mkString "\n"
    case _ => "- "
  }
```

After upgrading my project from Scala 2.11 to 2.12, it would no longer compile. Error:

```
CaseClassString.scala:14: value toStream is not a member of java.util.stream.Stream[String]
```

I tried rewriting like this:

```
private def indent ( s : String )
  = Stream(s.lines) match {
    case h +: t =>
      ( ("- " + h) +: t.map{"| " + _} ) mkString "\n"
    case _ => "- "
  }
```

But it is not working.

This method was found in the following project:
https://github.com/nikita-volkov/sext

The function would transform a string like:

```
metricResult: column: value: city
function: density
value: metricValue: 0.1
```

to:

```
- metricResult: column: value: city
| - function: density
| - value: metricValue: 0.1
```

Anyone have other ideas about how to rewrite this method for Scala 2.12?

Comment: What is the method supposed to do ? There have been lot of changes (specially on Java's side) since Scala 2.11, you can just look at the updated documentation instead of trying random things. What is your current Java version ?

Comment: Updated the question with details on what it does.  I am using Java 1.8

Comment: Where are the nested `- `s in 3rd and 4th columns supposed to come from? When applied to `"foo\nbar\nbaz"`, it produces `"- foo\n| bar\n| baz"`, not `"-foo\n| - bar\n| - baz"`?

Comment: This error shows that you are working with Java 11 or later :: `CaseClassString.scala:14: value toStream is not a member of java.util.stream.Stream[String]`

Comment: Mystery to me, then.  My IntelliJ project is using Java 8.. I don't even have 11 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like that you not only upgraded Scala but also upgraded Java version. The error is simple to understand if you simply look at changes related to `String` for both Java and Scala.

```scala
import scala.collection.immutable.StringOps

def indent(s : String): String =
  (s: StringOps).lines.toStream match {
    case h +: t =>
      ( ("- " + h) +: t.map{"| " + _} ) mkString "\n"
    case _ => "- "
  }
```

Or, if you are working with Java 11 and don't really need Stream then,

```scala
def indent(s : String): String =
  s.lines.toArray.toList match {
  case h :: t =>
    val indented = ("- " + h) :: t.map{"| " + _}
    indented.mkString("\n")
  case _ => "- "
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you've also upgraded your JVM from Java 8 to Java 11 (or are using code written to run on Java 8 on Java 11).  Java 11 added a `lines` method to `String` which results in a `java.util.Stream[String]`.  On Java 8, there's no `lines` method for `String` which means that the Scala compiler can implicitly convert a `String` to `scala.collection.immutable.StringOps` which has a `lines` method with result type `Iterator[String]`.

The trick here is to be explicit that you want to use `StringOps.lines` instead of `String.lines`, so something like

```scala
val lines = (s: scala.collection.immutable.StringOps).lines
lines.toStream match {
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: Note that it's also possible to convert the Java stream into a Scala iterator, though that would break if compiled against Java 8.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  @sarveshseri had the same idea.  I didn't actually change to Java 11, but thats also on the todo list.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to Andrey's solution, but working:

```
def indent(s: String) = s.linesIterator.mkString("- ", "\n| - ", "")
```

Code run at [scatie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MAUkb8WhRWaC7zvZpMjtCQ).